# Defining page margins with \geometry for two-sided documents

Tags: margins, double-sided, geometry

How do you set page margins using `\geometry` for a two-sided document? So far I've used the `twoside` option in my `documentclass`, which automatically widens the left/right margin on opposite sides of odd and even pages.

**Edit:** My inquiry is not strictly practical, as I wish to know how to achieve the same results 'without' the `twoside` option.

Comment: LaTeX *must* know that you want a twoside document. How could it do otherwise? The fact is that `oneside` is the default option for `article`, like `twoside` is for `book`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Normally, one would simply use the `left` and `right` keys, because they are actually synonyms for `inner` and `outer` in `twoside` mode. (Alternatively, one could specify the `textwidth` and `hmarginratio` keys.) In case you want to disable the swapping of margins on alternate pages, add the `asymmetric` option.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=4cm,left=1.5cm,right=3cm,asymmetric]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

EDIT: So far you've used the `twoside` option in your document class, but you want to do without this option? Well, use the `twoside` option of `geometry` instead.

Comment: In a practical sense, that would be perfect. But what if I were to use `geometry` without the `twoside` option?

Comment: @AymanElmasry Please edit your question and specify what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: It would be really useful if you explained why you want to avoid the `twoside` option, because its purpose is to typeset two-sided document and does its job correctly.

Comment: is it possible to define a four-sided document? My reason is that I print two pages on one page, and double-sided; so there are four different pages on one sheet of paper. The document is divided into several chapters, and if I want to work on one chapter, I would like to be able to just exchange that chapter's pages, which requires that every chapter starts only at page 4n+1.