# What's wrong with this attempt to keep the baselinegrid?

Tags: grid-typesetting

I have the following code; it is a fairly, but not completely minimal setup for use with XeLaTeX that approaches my real-world scenario (the somewhat weird specific numbers come from the design decision to use a 7mm grid with some items taking 14mm and have normal text to occupy three lines per two grid rows, which makes them 2 * 7 / 3 = 4.667mm high. Regardless, the visible background grid is set to this resulting lineheight. I use `fixltx2e` because i heard it manages to fix 'some problems with LaTeX's way of handling lengths'. The `\lineskiplimit`, `\lineskip` and `\topskip` settings are what *should* make the lines keep to the grid:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{leading}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage[
  % asymmetric,% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42051/28067
  driver=xetex,
  showframe,%
  left=14mm,%
  right=14mm,%
  top=14mm,%
  headsep=0mm,%
  headheight=0mm,%
  bottom=14mm,%
  footskip=0mm,%
  marginparsep=0mm,%
  marginparwidth=0mm,%
  includehead=false,%
  includefoot=false,%
  includemp=false,%
  paperwidth=70mm,%
  paperheight=70mm,%
  ]{geometry}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{EB Garamond 12 Regular}
\newdimen\myLineheight
\newdimen\myFontsize
\myFontsize=3.5mm
\myLineheight=4.6667mm
\fontsize{\myFontsize}{\myLineheight}
%\leading{\myLineheight}%
\setlength{\baselineskip}{\myLineheight}
\setlength{\parskip}{0mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
% % thx to http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88bazargan.pdf for the next:
\lineskiplimit=-10pt%
\lineskip=0pt%
\topskip=\baselineskip%
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{pagegrid}
\pagegridsetup{top-left,step=\myLineheight,arrows=false}


\begin{document}

helo

x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x

\end{document}
```

However, this is what i get:

[image]

I've found out that i do get the intended output by using

```
\usepackage[fontsize=\myFontsize,baseline=\myLineheight,lines=9]{grid}
```

but i'd still really like to know what's missing or wrong with my MWE?

**Update** The accepted solution works—`\fontsize{\myFontsize}{\myLineheight}\selectfont` should come within the document body, not in the preamble. That said, the last line is still missing; apparently, LaTeX judges the available space to be not high enough. Using the `grid` package as mentioned above fixes that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want (at least)

```
\begin{document}
\fontsize{\myFontsize}{\myLineheight}\selectfont
```

as `\fontsize` without `\selectfont` doesn't change the font or baseline and at `\begin{document}` latex does `\normalsize` (which set 12pt baselineskip as you
had set `\baselineskip` in the preamble but not changed the default baselineskip or font size).